# Why does it say I'm missing a parenthesis?

Tags: java

```
public class RacingKarel extends SuperKarel
{
    public void run()
    {
        race();
    }
    
    private void race()
    {
        if(frontIsClear())
        {
            move();
        }
        else
        {
            turnLeft();
        }
    }
    
    private void dropBalls()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 8)
        {
            putBall();
        }
    }
    

}
```

I'm getting this message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
You might be missing a ( or have an extra )
```

I don't see it. This is for my computer science class on codeHS.

Comment: Actually the error being displayed right here is `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'class'` You have tagged this question with `JavaScript`, but your code is `Java`, which are two completely separate languages.

Comment: mssing 3rd part of the for loop header

Comment: You _might_ be missing a `(` or have an extra `)` but that's just a guess by the compiler. The actual error is "unexpected token )" which tells you that somewhere in your code, there is a `)` that shouldn't be where it is right now. You've put it either too early or too late in the code. Others already explain what you did wrong, but if you aren't using an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ yet, start using an IDE because they will flag these things for you as you write them. Don't use a plain text editor or a "plain" VS Code or Sublime: they don't catch errors as you make them, and you need that.

Comment: `Unexpected token ')'` doesn't mean you are missing `)` but that there *is* a `)` in an unexpected place. In your case `for(int i = 0; i < 8)` misses third part which is *incrementation* section like `for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`. If you don't want to add any code responsible for incrementation (like when you want to create infinite loop) you can leave that section empty like `for(int i = 0; i < 8; )` (notice that there is an `;` after `i < 8`).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the second semicolon and increment in the for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```